# Is there a concurrency/deadlock problem in this Golang code?

Tags: go, concurrency, timeout, deadlock, goroutine

I think I have concurrency problem with the code below. It so strange because it works on my local computer where I have 2 threads available, but not on a another machine where there is 4 threads available. The execution can hang for minutes or even much more on the last machine.

I just want to check by others to see if there is some kind of deadlock in the code since it hangs in the first case but not in the last case.

The problem seems to be that it does not continue with the second for loop in the importantJob function, because it does not continue the excecution in the doItemJob function after it returns from its timeout function. So the last message to the console before it hangs is the one from the timeOut function: "We have timed out in %v seconds and can now proceed".

The code is a little pseudo, but not when it comes to the goroutines etc.

All tips and comments on what can be the problem will be very appreciated.

```
func main() {
    config, err := server.GetConfig()
    newServer, err := server.NewServer(config)
    worker := cron.Worker{}
    worker.Start()                                      <<<<<<<   THE INTERESTING FUNCTION                                    
    // Listen for user requests
    runError := newServer.Run(8080)
    if runError != nil {
        log.Fatal(runError)
    }
}

type item struct {
    key string
    value []byte
}

func(worker *Worker) Start() {
    go worker.beginJobClock(30)
    go worker.beginJobClock2(1, 3)
}

func(worker *Worker) beginJobClock(timeInterval int) {
    log.Println("Begin job clock")
    for {
        worker.importantJob()
        timeOut(timeInterval, false)
    }
}

func(worker *Worker) beginJobClock2(timeInterval, hourToExecute int) {
    for {
        hourNow := time.Now().Hour()
        if hourNow == hourToExecute {
            worker.importantJob2()
        }
        timeOut(timeInterval, true)
    }
}

func (worker *Worker) importantJob() {
    log.Println("START IMPORTANT JOB")

    // Get items
    items := fromDB()

    // Spin up go-routines
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan item, len(items))
    for i, it := range items {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id, url string){
            defer wg.Done()
            ch <- item{key: id, value: worker.doItemJob(id, url)}
        }(it.ID, it.URL)
    }
    wg.Wait()                                             
    close(ch)
    for val := range ch {                                <<<<<<<   IT DOES NOT CONTINUE HERE, CAN TAKE 5 MINUTES BEFORE IT DOES OR EVEN NOT AT ALL
        log.Println("Cacheservice: ", val.key)
        worker.CacheService.WriteValueToCache(val.key, val.value)
    }
}

func timeOut(t int, isHour bool) {
    var duration time.Duration
    if isHour {
        duration = time.Duration(int64(t)) * time.Hour
    } else {
        duration = time.Duration(int64(t)) * time.Second
    }
    c1 := make(chan string, 1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(duration)
        c1 <- "I have finished my sleep"
    }()
    select {
    case <-c1:
        log.Printf("We have timed out in %v seconds and can now proceed", t)
        close(c1)
        return
    }
}

func (worker *Worker) doItemJob(id, url string) []byte {
    // Start job (connect to browser)...
    // Wait s.t everything gets loaded by timing out the goroutine:
    timeOut(10, false)
    // continue job (take screenshot of website)...        <<<<<<<      IT DOES NOT CONTINUE HERE WHEN WE RETURN FROM THE TIMEOUT FUNCTION....
    // return result
}
```

Comment: Use [the goroutine profiles](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) to check if and where goroutines are blocked.

Comment: Note that `select` with a single `case` is the same that the operation performed in that single `case` itself. Also there's no point in sleeping inside a goroutine and communicating the "sleep is done" back into the calling one—just sleep "in place".

Comment: A shot in the dark: are you sure `worker.CacheService.WriteValueToCache` cannot hang for 5 minutes—seemingly making `range ch` appear to be stuck? Still, I'm with Peter on this: Go allows you to take "snapshots" of the stacks of all running goroutines which makes it quite easy to understand where each goroutine is being blocked. You can even do this w/o using the pprof package: sending SIGQUIT (`ctrl-\\` on a PC) to the foreground process in a Unix console would make it dump those stacks and terminate.